# SQLBulkCopy and Transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to copy data from 2 `DataTable`s in C# to a SQL Server. The tables are related by a `ParentId`. I have wrapped the `SqlBulkCopy` for each of the `DataTable` in a single transaction. The SQL Server table where I will be writing the data into also has the `ParentId` with Identity set to Yes.

I'm writing the parent `DataTable` to the server using

```
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(parentDataTable);
```

Now I want to be able to update the `ParentId` in the child data table with the new `ParentId` from SQL Server. However the parent data table still has the original `ParentId` and not the SQL Server `ParentId`.

How can I get the the `ParentId` of the parent data table after the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` call?

Comment: You want to change the primary key of multiple tables.  See following posting to explain issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919127/change-primary-key-value

Comment: ON UPDATE CASCADE is a terrible idea. I wouldn't allow it in any system unless there was a really, really good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if you use this then you can just insert into the new tables using the old ParentId (make sure the ParentId is part of your insert query - it won't fail if that `SET` option is enabled).

If you do actually need to alter the ParentId (say, if there's existing data in the table), then you need to do it *before* the bulk insert, so you still need to set identity_insert.  If you try and do it afterwards you're out of luck because the link between the parent and child tables is *gone*.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to map whatever columns you like using the `[ColumnMappings][1]` property of the `SqlBulkCopy` object.